# authentication using rest_client, 401 unauthorized asana api

Tags: ruby, authentication, automation, rest-client, asana

I am trying to get response from asana rest api. But It returns me 401 unauthorized error. I am using the below code to get response:

```
    require 'base64'
    require 'rest_client'
    @user='mailid'
    @pass='YWlzNydXNoMTIz\n'
    @url="https://app.asana.com"
    response = RestClient::Request.new(
    :method => :get,
    :url => @url + "/" + "api/1.0/users/me",
    :user => @user,
    :password => Base64.decode64(@pass),

  ).execute
  @results = JSON.parse(response.to_str)
  p @results
```

I am getting this error /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 401 Unauthorized (RestClient::Unauthorized)

please tell the problem with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use HTTP Basic Authentication, but you need to pass the API Key as the username (and no password) as described in the [Developer Documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#api_keys). So, it should looks something like:

```
@api_key='FcZ23.M4xsMtXmTKmDA4ssLCkEnYi'
...
:user => @api_key,
:password => ""
```

You can get your API Key from your Account Settings > Apps > API Key.